# Реализовать метод производящий вычитание двух окружностей

Tags: python

Реализовать метод производящий вычитание двух окружностей, вычитание радиусов произвести по модулю. Если вычитаются две окружности с одинаковым значением радиуса, то результатом вычитания будет точка класса Point.
Вот пример кода

```
import math


class Point():

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __add__(self, other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y + other.y
        return Point(x, y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'

    def distance_from_origin(self):
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)


class Circle(Point):

    def __init__(self, radius, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = radius

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.radius == other.radius

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()[:-1] + f', radius={self.radius})'

    def __add__(self, other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y + other.y
        radius = self.radius + other.radius
        return Circle(radius, x, y)

    def edge_distance_from_origin(self):
        return abs(self.distance_from_origin() - self.radius)

    def circumference(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius**2)
```

Основной код вроде как правильно а дальше подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну разность точек - вектор, сумма математически не определена. А что должно получаться при сложении или вычитании окружностей?  Как-то это... маразмом попахивает. Впрочем, раз такое задание, и методы add у вас есть, делайте по их подобию

Comment: Там мне подсказывали через метод __sub__ почитав за него, я не понял как его реализовать

Comment: `__sub__` точно так же, как `__add__`

Comment: объясните понятными словами - что такое вычитание окружностей

Comment: Сам переспросил у руководителя , получил такой ответ: Мы сейчас не можем написать: a = "plan text" b = "plan " c = a - b и при этом значение с было "text". Так как невозможно из одной строки вычесть другую. А мы создаём новый класс на базе класса str. Кстати, новый класс надо объявлять так: class String(str): описать его так, чтобы вышеописанные операции были возможны для нового класса:  a = String("plan text") b = String("plan ") c = a - b при этом значение переменной с будет "text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задание не сосем очевидно, но дословно это будет примерно так

```
def __sub__(self, other):
    x = self.x - other.x
    y = self.y - other.y
    radius = abs(self.radius - other.radius)
    return Circle(radius, x, y) if radius else Point(x,y)
```

Comment: спасибо но я сделал чуть по другому , не успел выложить. У вас чуть более кратко вышло ))

Comment: расписал метод sub просто для классов по отдельности, тоже работало

Answer (score 0):

```
    def __sub__(self, other):
        x = self.x - other.x
        y = self.y - other.y
        radius = self.radius - other.radius
        return Point(radius, x, y)
```

примерно так , в классе Circle прописал

Comment: в задании *вычитание радиусов произвести по модулю*, вы не думаете, чо подразумевается - радиус не может быть отрицательным. во-2х, Point создается без радиуса, только по координатам